# Unable to connect NodeJs application with Postgres running in Minikube

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am getting started with helm to carry out deployments to Kubernetes and i am stuck while connecting Nodejs application with postgres DB.  I am using helm to carry out the deployment to K8.

Below is my YAML file for application

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ template "service-chart.fullname" . }}-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ template "service-chart.fullname" . }}-converstionrate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ template "service-chart.fullname" . }}-converstionrate
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: {{ template "service-chart.fullname" . }}-converstionrate
          image: <application_image>
          env:
            - name: DB_URL
              value: postgres://{{ template "postgres.fullname" . }}.default.svc.cluster.local:5432/{{ .Values.DbName }}

---

kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: {{ template "service-chart.fullname" . }}-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: {{ template "service-chart.fullname" . }}-converstionrate
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      targetPort: 3000
```

Below is my requirement file where i am using the postgres dependency

```
dependencies:
  - name: postgresql
    version: "8.1.2"
    repository: "https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/"
```

Below is application code where i try to connect to DB:-

```
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  // sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
  sequelize = new Sequelize(
    process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
    process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
    process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
    pocess.env.POSTGRES_DIALECT
  );
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(
    config.database,
    config.username,
    config.password,
    config
  );
}
```

What i am not able to understand is how to connect to the DB as with the above i am not able to.?
Can anyone please help me out here.?

I am newbie with helm hence not able to figure it out. I have looked into lot of blogs but some how it is not clear on how it needs to be done. As the DB is running in one POD and Node app in another so how do i wire it up together.? How to set the env variables of DB in yaml to be consumed.?

FYI --- I am using minikube to deploy as of now.

The application code is available:- at https://github.com/Vishesh30/Node-express-Postgress-helm

Thanks,
Vishesh.

Comment: Are you facing any error? if so could you please add them here

Comment: How about your `values.yaml` file? You could use values.yaml file to pass variables to your service template, take a look in this [link](https://docs.bitnami.com/kubernetes/how-to/create-your-first-helm-chart/). What HELM and Kubernetes version you are using?

Comment: The environment variables your code is using (`POSTGRES_HOST`, _etc._) don't match what you're setting in the Kubernetes YAML file (`DB_URL`).  You need to make those match.

Comment: @TummalaDhanvi Yes, when i try to query the DB it gives error                                                {
"name": "SequelizeHostNotFoundError",
"parent": {
"errno": "ENOTFOUND",
"code": "ENOTFOUND",
"syscall": "getaddrinfo",
"hostname": "elder-kudu.default.svc.cluster.local",
"host": "elder-kudu.default.svc.cluster.local",
"port": 5432
},
"original": {
"errno": "ENOTFOUND",
"code": "ENOTFOUND",
"syscall": "getaddrinfo",
"hostname": "elder-kudu.default.svc.cluster.local",
"host": "elder-kudu.default.svc.cluster.local",
"port": 5432
}
}

Comment: @DavidMaze . Thanks for pointing it out i have changed it but, still no difference. Can you tell me where i should pass the value of POSTGRES_USER and POSTGRES_PASSWORD  from.?

Comment: The application code is available at https://github.com/Vishesh30/Node-express-Postgress-helm in case you would want to have a look

Comment: could you please give the output of `kubectl get service`

Comment: @TummalaDhanvi Below is output of the command                                                        NAME                                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes                           ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP          20h
lame-markhor-service-chart-service   NodePort    10.105.209.120   <none>        8080:30718/TCP   41m

Comment: Is the service for postgres in that list?

Comment: Yes it is listed. However i tried a different approach to solve the issue . Instead of download the chart for postgres i created a simple one for myself which works fine now. Somehow using an existing postgres chart is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

As a mentioned by @David Maze, you need to fix the variable name from `DB_URL` to `POSTGRES_HOST`, but there are some other things I could see.

I've tried to reproduce you scenario and the following works for me:

You need to fix the service dns from you YAML file:

```
postgres://{{ template "postgres.fullname" . }}.default.svc.cluster.local:5432/{{ .Values.DbName }}
```

to

```
postgres://{{ template "postgresql.fullname" . }}-postgresql.default.svc.cluster.local:5432/{{ .Values.DbName }}
```

After that you need to pass to your application the host, database username and password of the database, you can do it overriding the postgresql default variables (because it's a subchart from you aplication), as describe in [Helm documentaion](https://v3.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals/) and inject to you container using environment variables.

There's a lot of variables, see here.

Add this values to you `values.yaml` in order to override postgresql defaults:

```
postgresql:
  postgresqlUsername: dbuser 
  postgresqlPassword: secret # just for example
```

You can create a secret file to store the password:

service-chart/templates/secrets.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: dbconnection
type: Opaque
stringData:
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: {{ .Values.postgresql.postgresqlPassword }
```

> If you don't want keep the password in file, maybe you can try some automation process to >rewrite you file before the deployment. You can read more about secrets [here.](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/)

Now in you `deployment.yaml` add the variables, the `POSTGRES_USERNAME` will be get from `values.yaml` file, and the value to `POSTGRES_PASSWORD`:

```
          env:
            - name: POSTGRES_HOST 
              value: postgres://{{ template "postgresql.fullname" . }}-postgresql.default.svc.cluster.local:5432/{{ .Values.DbName }}
            - name: POSTGRES_USERNAME
              value: {{ .Values.postgresql.postgresqlUsername }}
            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: dbconnection
                  key: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
```

After the deployment you can check the container's environment variables.

I really hope it helps you!